# Error while configuring "Wix Toolset" plugin in Jenkins for MSBUILD setup project

Tags: wix

I am new to WiX Toolset,I have configured Wix Toolset plugin in Jenkins. To build Solution I used MSBUILD. When I try run setup project which is giving below error.

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at de.berg.systeme.jenkins.wix.Toolset.compile(Toolset.java:142)
at de.berg.systeme.jenkins.wix.WixToolsetBuilder.perform(WixToolsetBuilder.java:164)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
at `hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)`
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
```

Build step 'WIX Toolset' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'WIX Toolset' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: What version of Jenkins and plugin do you use?

Comment: Have you tried to build wix installer on Jenkins without this plugin? It's pretty easy with msbuild and WIX Toolset been intsalled on slave, so plugin seems not to be necessary at all.